# Python tcp/ip Server port in use

Tags: python, linux, tcpclient

I have a tcp server running that serves to two devices (clients). When I open the connection from a client and send data, I get the response as expected.
However, if I close the client connection and open again, I get "port already in use".
I am already setting socket.SO_REUSEADDR but there isn't the solution.
It is running into Linux Ubuntu.

```
import socket
import select

#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
    CONNECTION_LIST = []    # list of socket clients
    RECV_BUFFER = 4096
    PORT = 50001
         
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', PORT))   
    server_socket.listen(10)
 
    # Add server socket to the list of readable connections
    CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_socket)
 
    print("Server started on port " + str(PORT))
 
    while 1:
        # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(CONNECTION_LIST,[],[])
 
        for sock in read_sockets:
             
            #New connection
            if sock == server_socket:
                # Handle the case in which there is a new connection received through server_socket
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                CONNECTION_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print("Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr)
                 
            #Some incoming message from a client
            else:
                # Data recieved from client, process it
                try:
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    print(data)

            if data.startswith("CLIENT1_"):
                         sock.sendall("client1")         

            elif data.startswith("CLIENT2_"):
                         sock.sendall("client2")                 
                 
                # client disconnected, so remove from socket list
                except:
                    #broadcast_data(sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                    print("Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                    sock.close()
                    CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock)
                    continue
         
    
    server_socket.close()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't show full errorm message - it is not clear if problem is in server or maybe client has problem to reuse port. BTW: if client finish connection then it should use `close()` to make sure system close socket.

Comment: your code has wrong indetations - we can't run it.

Comment: I tested your client on Linux using [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) as  client and all work correctly. As for me you have mistake in your client code - but you didn't show this code so I can confirm it.

Comment: or maybe you should use `try/except` or `try/finally` to run `server_socket.close()` when you close server using `Ctrl+C`. `SO_REUSEADDR` will not work if you don't use `server_socket.close()`

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess that you use `Ctrl+C` to stop server - but it raises error and script doesn't run `server_socket.close()`. And if it doesn't run `server_socket.close()` then socket is still open and `SO_REUSEADDR` can't change it.

You have to use `server_socket.close()` to close socket.

`SO_REUSEADDR` is only to release `PORT` after correct `close`. It only inform system that it has to release `PORT` at once after closing without blocking `PORT` for short time - but this need to close socket correctly.

So you need `try/except` or `try/finally` to run `server_socket.close()`

```
    try:
        server_socket = socket.socket(...)
        # ... code ...
    finally:
        server_socket.close()
```